# Python sending mail only to the last mail address in the excel sheet

Tags: python

Hi everyone I am trying to create a mailing system in python which pulls the email address from the excel sheets but I am facing an i.e. the code is always sending the  mail to the last mail address in the excel sheet
here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.application.CreateItem(0)
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/vkhar12/Desktop/zack.xlsx")
a=df["Email"]
for Email in mailto:
    mail.To = Email
    mail.Subject = "hey"
    mail.Body ="hey attemp 1"
 mail.send
```

please help me out
the "mailto" is the list containing the email address as a tried to append them in the list but it still does the same
please help me out I am stuck at it from 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Your `mail.send` line is outside of your for-loop. Hence it only sends a single email after the for-loop is completed. Include it in your for-loop by properly indenting your code. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.application.CreateItem(0)
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/vkhar12/Desktop/zack.xlsx")
a=df["Email"]
for Email in mailto:
    mail.To = Email
    mail.Subject = "hey"
    mail.Body ="hey attemp 1"
    mail.send
```